# “If” Clause, Type 3, and Perfect Tense

Tags: perfect-constructions

> "If he had come yesterday, he might have seen his sister."

This sentence implies he ***didn't*** come yesterday and ***didn't*** see his sister.

> "If he has come YESTERDAY, he may have seen his sister."

İ know that i cannot use this sentence with YESTERDAY to imply that i don't know whether he came or not.

Why is it possible to use it with past perfect,  when I know that the action didn't happen and I imagine an unreal situation about this past action ?

Comment: Sorry İ dont understand

Answer (score 2):

1. In your first sentence the construction "If he had come" is not an ordinary past perfect: it is employed to express the unreality of a past event.

   You might find my answer at [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/9801/32) helpful.
2. In your second sentence, present perfect is a *present* tense construction, not a past tense, and may not be used with temporal expressions such as "yesterday" which do not include the present. What you want here is an ordinary past tense expressing a possible event, one which may or may not have happened:

   > If he came yesterday he may have seen his sister.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on why you think 'yesterday' would not work in the second example?

Comment: And i want to learn is it correct to add here a time marking "İf he had come yesterday at 5 p.m.,he might have seen his sister" ? With this sentence do i imagine that he came here at 5 p.m. or he had already come,already came at 5 p.m ?

Comment: @HelpMe911 You imagine that he came at 5 pm, knowing that in fact he did not come at 5 pm.